# Summarise tibble to multiple rows of output

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Suppose I have the following tibble in R:

```
activation_date | country | campaign | revenue | users
======================================================
1               | 1       | 1        | R_1     | U_1
2               | 1       | 1        | R_2     | U_2
3               | 1       | 1        | R_3     | U_3
1               | 1       | 2        | R_4     | U_4
2               | 1       | 2        | R_5     | U_5
3               | 1       | 2        | R_6     | U_6
1               | 2       | 3        | R_7     | U_7
2               | 2       | 3        | R_8     | U_8
3               | 2       | 3        | R_9     | U_9
```

I want to group this tibble by country and summarise its data to have this tibble as its output:

```
country | campaign | ltv
==========================
1       | 1        | ltv_1
1       | 2        | ltv_2
2       | 3        | ltv_3
```

However, I want both `ltv_1` *and* `ltv_2` to use all of `R_1` through `R_6` and `U_1` through `U_6` to be jointly calculated, and `ltv_3` to use `R_7` through `R_9` and `U_7` through `U_9` to be calculated.

I can't `group_by` "country" and `summarise`, because that gets rid of the "campaign" column which I want to keep, but I can't `group_by` both "country" and "campaign" either because then I won't be able to use the first three lines to help calculate `ltv_2` nor the subsequent three to help calculate `ltv_1`.

One possible way to do this would be grouping by "country" and using the [`group_modify`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html) function to generate the grouped output tibbles. However, that function is in the "experimental" stage so I don't want to rely on it too heavily. Is there a different, established way to do this?

---

An example input tibble would be:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
  activation_date country campaign revenue users
            <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1               1       1        1       1    11
2               2       1        1       2    12
3               3       1        1       3    13
4               1       1        2       4    14
5               2       1        2       5    15
6               3       1        2       6    16
7               1       2        3       7    17
8               2       2        3       8    18
9               3       2        3       9    19
```

And its output would be:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  country campaign   ltv
    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1        1 0.213
2       1        2 0.296
3       2        3 0.444
```

With the code that generated it, using the `group_modify` function, being:

```
test_tibble = tribble (~ activation_date, ~ country, ~ campaign, ~ revenue, ~ users,
                       1, 1, 1, 1, 11,
                       2, 1, 1, 2, 12,
                       3, 1, 1, 3, 13,
                       1, 1, 2, 4, 14,
                       2, 1, 2, 5, 15,
                       3, 1, 2, 6, 16,
                       1, 2, 3, 7, 17,
                       2, 2, 3, 8, 18,
                       3, 2, 3, 9, 19)

test_function = function (activation_date, campaign, revenue, users) {
    total_ltv = sum (revenue) / sum (users)
    campaign_ltv = double (0)
    campaign_names = unique (campaign)
    for (c in campaign_names) {
        campaign_ltv = c (campaign_ltv, sum (revenue [campaign == c]) / sum (users [campaign == c]))
    }

    return (tibble (campaign = campaign_names,
                    ltv = campaign_ltv / 2 + total_ltv / 2))
}


test_tibble %>%
    group_by (country) %>%
    group_modify (~ test_function (.x$activation_date, .x$campaign, .x$revenue, .x$users)) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: What is `ltv` calculation? Also, it'd be better if you put in some numbers for `revenue`. Ideally, your example data structure should represent your actual data structure.

Comment: I could put in some made-up numbers, but why do the actual values or the actual calculation matter? `ltv_1` has to be a function of `R_1` through `U_6`, `ltv_2` also has to be a function of `R_1` through `U_6`, they may or may not be the same function so let's assume w.l.o.g. they're not, how do I do this?

Comment: It matters because result would be easier to validate.

Comment: Fair enough, I've added an example to the question.

Comment: I'd suggest that if you don't want to use `group_modify` (which I agree is the natural fit here) you could use `split` with `purrr::map_dfr`

Comment: I'd love to use `group_modify` but with the looming possibility that its syntax may change at any point with no warning I don't want to put anything in production that uses it. I'll look into those functions you suggested, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1 -

A bit verbose but *transparent* way of doing this is with `joins`. However, it's not that verbose considering the code in `test_function` as well. -

```
test_tibble %>% 
  group_by(country, campaign) %>% 
  summarize(campaign_ltv = sum(revenue)/sum(users)) %>% 
  inner_join(
    test_tibble %>% 
      group_by(country) %>% 
      summarise(total_ltv = sum(revenue)/sum(users)),
    by = "country"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(ltv = (total_ltv + campaign_ltv)/2) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  country campaign campaign_ltv total_ltv   ltv
    <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1       1        1        0.167     0.259 0.213
2       1        2        0.333     0.259 0.296
3       2        3        0.444     0.444 0.444
```

---

#### Option 2) -

Wrap `test_function` output in a `list` to get as a nested tibble and use `unnest`.

```
test_tibble %>%
  group_by (country) %>%
  mutate(
    ltv = list(test_function(activation_date, campaign, revenue, users))
  ) %>%
  select(country, ltv) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  country campaign   ltv
    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1        1 0.213
2       1        2 0.296
3       2        3 0.444
```

#### Option 3) -

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(nesting(country, campaign), nesting(revenue, users)) %>% 
  group_by(campaign, add = TRUE)
  # now you have all revenue and users for each country-campaign
  # for total_ltv: use revenue and users as is
  # for campaign_ltv: use revenue and users where activation_date is not NA

# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   country, campaign [3]
   country campaign revenue users activation_date
     <int>    <int> <chr>   <chr>           <int>
 1       1        1 R_1     U_1                 1
 2       1        1 R_2     U_2                 2
 3       1        1 R_3     U_3                 3
 4       1        1 R_4     U_4                NA
 5       1        1 R_5     U_5                NA
 6       1        1 R_6     U_6                NA
 7       1        2 R_1     U_1                NA
 8       1        2 R_2     U_2                NA
 9       1        2 R_3     U_3                NA
10       1        2 R_4     U_4                 1
11       1        2 R_5     U_5                 2
12       1        2 R_6     U_6                 3
13       2        3 R_7     U_7                 1
14       2        3 R_8     U_8                 2
15       2        3 R_9     U_9                 3
```

Demo with `test_tibble` -

```
test_tibble %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(nesting(country, campaign), nesting(revenue, users)) %>% 
  group_by(campaign, add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(
    ltv = sum(revenue)/sum(users)/2 + 
      sum(revenue[!is.na(activation_date)])/sum(users[!is.na(activation_date)])/2
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  country campaign   ltv
    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1        1 0.213
2       1        2 0.296
3       2        3 0.444
```

Comment: So the problem with that is that it's not general enough; it solves the problem for the _specific_ example function I used in my question, but that was just an example, the functions I want to apply are much less specific and simple than that.

Comment: Complexity of your functions is irrelevant. As long as it outputs 1 value per group (for `country`, and `country-campaign` combo) this code will work. If the function output length is more than 1 then you can always wrap it in a list and use `unnest()`.

Comment: Yes, it is not in fact the case that the function I'm interested in outputs one value per group. The function I want to apply is actually a Kalman filter on the time vector of the campaign LTVs within a country, and that cannot be reduced to this case.